# Queue listen - not working when database connection changes by hitting on sub-domain

Tags: php, laravel

We have main domain and sub-domains like : abc.com and test.abc.com.
on main domain we use primary DB (DATABASE_URL in ENV file) and on Sub-domain we use (DATABASE_URL_TEST in ENV file) based on subdomain name and DB connection changes on hitting the sub-domain.

On register process we trigger a email via Background job. It is save in DB (On current DB connection) but not running on `queue:listen`.

`queue:listen` working only on main domain D i.e set in (DATABASE_URL).

Answer (score 1):

Just add a alternative connection in config/queue.php.
And add a second listen. for ex:

```
php artisan queue:listen second_conn
```

Comment: Hi @jtwes,
```
'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'expire' => 60,
        ]

    ],
```
Above my code in `queue,php`. Using QUEUE_DRIVER=database. 
So, What i need to change in it.
Can you please explain bit more?
Thanks!

Comment: for example add 'database_2' => ['driver' => 'database_2', ....]
In database.php (in config) add database_2 with your credentials...

Answer (score 0):

> Write this code in your bootstrap\app.php right before return $app:

`$envFile = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'aaa.xyz.com' ? '.env-aaa' : $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'bbb.xyz.com' ? '.env-bbb';
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);`

> Now follow the normal queue process, and it should work!